# Not able to post to target url by 'HttpPOST' action in microsoft teams message card

Tags: microsoft-teams, connector, office365connectors

I am posting a actionable message card to  Microsoft team's channel using custom incoming webhook. However, I am not able to hit the target url using 'HttpPOST' action. I have provided accurate target url. I am able to post to that url through other sources. Whenever I click on button with given action, 'Could not complete the requested action. Please try again later.' this message is displayed.
Following is my JSON for message card. Target url is dummy. Please help.

```
{
"@type": "MessageCard",
"@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
"themeColor": "0076D7",
"summary": "Larry Bryant created a new task",
"potentialAction": [{
    "@type": "ActionCard",
    "name": "Add a comment",
    "inputs": [{
        "@type": "TextInput",
        "id": "comment",
        "isMultiline": false,
        "title": "Add a comment here for this task"
    }],
    "actions": [{
        "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "Add comment",
        "body":"hello",
        "bodyContentType":"application/json",
        "target":"https://demo.xyz.com/abc"
    }]
}
]
```

}

Comment: Could you please take a look at [Microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp) sample code?

Comment: Is your target URL domain is added in valid doamins list in [Connector Portal](https://outlook.office.com/connectors/publish)?

Comment: @wajeed Issue is resolved now. I was using incoming webhook with free version of teams. It worked with teams developer license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved after using MS Teams with developer license.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "developer license"? We have the same problem, but using Teams in a standard Microsoft 365 Business subscription..

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich I faced this issue while using free version of teams, but issue resolved after using developer license.I think they have provided limited options in free version due to which I was not able to post the actionable message.
If you are using standard license, pls check your target URL.